# Orthogonal trajectories of circle

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, orthogonality

Find the orthogonal trajectories of follow circle.
$$(x+C)^2+y^2=C^2$$

My step is follow :

1. Find y' of original circle : $x+C+yy'=0,\ C={x^2+y^2\over -2x},\ y'={y^2-x^2\over 2xy}$
2. Replace y' to $-1/y'$ : $y'={2xy\over x^2-y^2}$

next is problem. How can I solve the equation $y'={2xy\over x^2-y^2}$ ?

Comment: Thanks for everyone who commented. But I found another way, the way was using the integrating factor. I mutiplied $x^{-2}$ as integrating factor to both sides.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively, I will show you how to solve this using polar coordinates (see section *In polar coordinates*, [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_trajectory)).

$x = r \cos\theta, y = r \sin \theta$

$(x+C)^2 + y^2 = C^2 \implies r = - 2 C \cos\theta$

[For $C \gt 0, \pi/2 \leq \theta \leq 3 \pi/2$ and for $C \lt 0, -\pi/2 \leq \theta \leq \pi/2$]

For $C \ne 0$, these are circles centered on x-axis with radius equal to the distance of the center from the origin i.e. y-axis is tangent to these circles.

As the pencil of curves is represented in polar coordinates by

$F(r, \theta, C) = r + 2 C \cos\theta = 0$

$F_r(r, \theta, C) + F_{\theta} (r, \theta, C) \cdot \theta' = 1 - 2C \sin \theta \cdot d\theta' = 0$

Substituting $C = - \cfrac{r}{2 \cos\theta}$ from $(1)$, we get

$1 + r \tan \theta \cdot d\theta = 0 \implies \theta' = f(r, \theta) = - \cfrac{\cot\theta}{r}$

So the differential equation of the orthogonal trajectories is,

$\theta' = - \cfrac{1}{r^2 f(r, \theta)} = \cfrac{1}{r \cot\theta}$

Integrating, $\ln r = \ln (\sin\theta) + c_1$

$\ln r = \ln (2 d \sin \theta) \implies r = 2 d  \sin\theta$

For $d \gt 0, 0 \leq \theta \leq \pi$ and for $d \lt 0, \pi \leq \theta \leq 2\pi$

In cartesian coordinates, you can write the equation of the circle as $x^2 + (y - d)^2 = d^2$

For $d \ne 0$, these are circles centered on y-axis with radius equal to the distance of the center from the origin i.e. x-axis is tangent to the circles. You can see why they are orthogonal trajectories to $(x+C)^2 + y^2 = C^2$.

Answer (score 0):

Substitute $y=xu$ then $y'=xu'+u $ and you otain $$u'x +u =\frac{2u}{1-u^2}$$
hence $$u'x =\frac{u+u^2}{1-u^2} $$
and $$\frac{1-u^2}{u^2 +u} du=\frac{dx}{x}$$
and we get $$\ln u -u =\ln x +C.$$

Comment: It should be $u'x=\frac{u+u^3}{1-u^2}$ rather than $u'x=\frac{u+u^2}{1-u^2}$

Answer (score 0):

$$y'={2xy\over x^2-y^2}$$
Now consider $x'$ instead of $y'$:
$$x^2-y^2=2xx'y$$
$$x^2-y^2=(x^2)'y$$
$$\dfrac {u'y-u}{y^2}=-1$$
$$\dfrac d {dy}\left (\dfrac  u y \right)=-1$$
Where $u=x^2$. Can you solve this DE ?